# Pass Service data to $scope controller AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have angular app with custom service, in service I request data from server via `$http` but I can't assign service data to `$scope`. Here is code for reference...

```
var app = angular.module('jokeRecords');
app.service('AtgService', function($http){
    // get method ajax....
    this.httpGet = function(url, params){
        $http.get(url, {params:params})
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                return response.data;
            }).catch(function(response) {
                console.log('get-catch');
                console.log(response);
            });
    };
});

// angular controller...
app.controller('jokeController', function($scope, $http, AtgService) {
    var sortColumn = 'id';
    var sortDirection = 'asc';
    $scope.jokes = AtgService.httpGet("/jokes", {'sortColumn': sortColumn, 'sortDirection': sortDirection });
});
```

When I use `$scope.jokes` in html it doesn't show anything.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in jokes">
 <td>{{x.joke_id}}</td>
 <td>{{ x.joke }}</td>
 <td>{{ x.submitted_by }}</td>
</tr>
```

Is there anything I am missing...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because request is async, so the "httpGet" function will return undefined, instead of response data. You need return $http promise on this function and use it to assign data in $scope on controller . Like that:

```
var app = angular.module('jokeRecords');
app.service('AtgService', function($http){
    // get method ajax....
    this.httpGet = function(url, params){
        return $http.get(url, {params:params});
    };
});

// angular controller...
app.controller('jokeController', function($scope, $http, AtgService) {
    var sortColumn = 'id';
    var sortDirection = 'asc';
    AtgService.httpGet("/jokes", {'sortColumn': sortColumn, 'sortDirection': sortDirection }).then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                $scope.jokes = response.data;
            }).catch(function(response) {
                console.log('get-catch');
                console.log(response);
            });
});
```

Hope this will help you !

Answer (score 0):

it can be done like this.

Service :

```
app.service('AtgService', function($http){
// get method ajax....
this.httpGet = function(url, params){
   var promise = $http.get(url, {params:params})
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
        }).catch(function(response) {
            console.log('get-catch');
            console.log(response);
        });
 return promise;
}; 
});
```

Controller :

```
app.controller('jokeController', function($scope, $http, AtgService) {
var sortColumn = 'id';
var sortDirection = 'asc';
  AtgService.httpGet("/jokes", {'sortColumn': sortColumn,'sortDirection': sortDirection }).then(function(data){
 $scope.jokes = data;
  },function(error){
  console.log(error in call);
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `AtgService` would be better returning a promise and then handling the response in your controller. Currently it's not returning anything which is why you're not seeing any data in `$scope.jokes`.

```
var app = angular.module('jokeRecords');
app.service('AtgService', function($http) 
{
    // get method ajax....
    this.httpGet = function(url, params) 
    {
        // return the promise
        return $http.get(url, {params:params});
    };
});

// angular controller...
app.controller('jokeController', function($scope, $http, AtgService) 
{
    // initialise jokes to be empty briefly
    $scope.jokes = [];

    var sortColumn = 'id';
    var sortDirection = 'asc';

    // run the function to populate $scope.jokes
    getJokes();

    function getJokes()
    {
        AtgService.httpGet("/jokes", {'sortColumn': sortColumn, 'sortDirection': sortDirection }).then(function (response) 
        {
            // here we're setting $scope.jokes to be the response of GET /jokes
            $scope.jokes = response;
        });
    }
});
```